# Would anyone know if the o2 sensor is the pre-cat or post-cat?

Tags: honda, maintenance, accord

i have a honda accord 2007. I had the car go for a diagnosis and its come up with faulty 'o2 sensor"?? Would anyone know if thats the pre-cat or post-cat?

Comment: As @juhist has said, you really need the codes.

Comment: are there running issues? typically post-cat only affects emissions, while pre-cat would cause running problems (poor mileage, etc)

Comment: The OBD code will tell you if it is upstream (precat) or downstream (postcat) and which bank if a v6,

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to know without asking them. They did the diagnosis, so they know. Next time, when doing diagnosis, please ask for the specific error code, that has way more information than the verbal diagnosis about failed O2 sensor.

Or, you can buy a cheap OBD2 scanning device so that you can have an error code already known. An OBD2 scanning device is handy even if you don't do repairs yourself. You can tell the garage which error code you have, and they can already order the parts before you leave your car there for a repair. I would say just one error code ever occurring justifies buying a cheap OBD2 scanning device.

Comment: most auto stores will run a scan for you for free as well.